# FATAL EXCEPTION Barcode Scanner plugin for Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried the Phonegap And Barcodescanner.

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3

"scanCode" click the link.
Then exit with an error of Android applications.

Log is as follows. What is wrong.

```
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity in loader
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk] 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1608)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:949)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 12-13 10:55:32.486:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3728) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 12-13 10:55:32.486:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-13 10:55:32.486:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3726): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity in loader
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk] 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 12-13
> 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):     at
> android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1600)
> 12-13 10:55:32.486: E/AndroidRuntime(3726):   ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the library project setup correctly. Here is a blog post I did on getting things setup correctly.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/installing-barcode-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: Thanks Simon MacDonald.
but same error appears in Eclipse LogCat (click link(scan();).
Then changed to the name of my application CaptureActivity app_name

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Maybe the old cache was working on the application.
Thank you anyway.